# Add a list item through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

So, I am trying to print out an array that gets user input text added to it, but what I want to print out is an ordered list of the array. As you can see, (if you run my code) the list item just keeps getting the user input added to it, and no new list items are added with people's names.

Here is the code below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 First name: <input type="text" id="firstname"><br> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var x= [];

 function changeText2(){
var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = firstname;
x.push(firstname);
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
 }
 </script>

 <p>Your first name is: <b id='boldStuff2'></b> </p> 
 <p> Other people's names: </p>
 
 <ol>
     <li id = "demo"> </li> 
 </ol>

 <input type='button' onclick='changeText2()'   value='Submit'/> 

 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `<head>` only contains meta information and links to resources, not actual content. But, the reason why you don't get a new list item is that you are not creating one.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you want to create a `li` element for each input/name, then you have to create it, with [`document.createElement` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).

Give the list the ID:

```
<ol id="demo"></ol>
```

and get a reference to it:

```
var list = document.getElementById('demo');
```

In your event handler, create a new list element with the input value as content and append to the list with [`Node.appendChild` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild):

```
var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
list.appendChild(entry);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gmyag/)

Comment: I would have exptected that adding text to li would be simpler, with something like entry.text ='foo'. Why do I need a `textnode`?

Comment: @Timo: It's been a while since I wrote that answer. I can't remember why I did it that way. But yes, you can absolutely do `entry.textContent = firstname;`.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I did a nested list based on your code, like ul-li-ul-li-/li-/ul-/li-/ul. I can imagine there is recursion for this when the list gets bigger, do you think a question here makes sense?

Comment: @Timo: I'd look around first. I'd imagine it has been asked before how to created a nested list from data.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/tik9/tik9.github.io/blob/main/t.html) is an example that could be improved.[here](https://github.com/tik9/tik9.github.io/blob/main/t2.html) is a nested loop but not what I want. I will go for the fquestion tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
var node=document.createElement("LI");
var textnode=document.createTextNode(firstname);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(node);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/3jDZd/

Answer (score 5):

I was recently presented with this same challenge and stumbled on this thread but found a simpler solution using append...

```
var firstname = $('#firstname').val();

$('ol').append( '<li>' + firstname + '</li>' );
```

Store the firstname value and then use `append` to add that value as an `li` to the `ol`. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer was helpful for me, but it might be useful (or best practice) to add the name on submit, as I wound up doing. Hopefully this will be helpful to someone. [CodePen Sample](https://codepen.io/jenstrickland/pen/Ozwbbv)

```
    <form id="formAddName">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Name </legend>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />

        <button>Add</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

      <ol id="demo"></ol>

<script>
    var list = document.getElementById('demo');
    var entry = document.getElementById('formAddName');
    entry.onsubmit = function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstName));
    list.appendChild(entry);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution, you can just create a `<li>` (with [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)), set its [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), and [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) it to the `<ol>`.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ol');
list.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('li'), {textContent: firstname}));
```

Demo:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const firstname = document.querySelector('#firstname').value;
  const list = document.querySelector('ol');
  list.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('li'), {textContent: firstname}));
});
```

```html
<label>First name: <input id="firstname"></label> <button>Submit</button>
<ol></ol>
```