# Adding users to the list using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add users to the list using javascript, I dont know why my code is not working.

Here is my code.

**HMTL**

```
<form id="myform">
    <h2>Add a User:</h2>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="name">
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <button onclick='addUser()' type="submit">add user</button>
</form>

<h2>UsersList:</h2>
<ul id="users"></ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var list = document.getElementById('users');
    function addUser(){
        var username =document.getElementById('username').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var entry = document.createElement('li');
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(username + '' + email));
        list.appendChild(entry);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how to add <li> in an existing <ul>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145208/jquery-how-to-add-li-in-an-existing-ul)

Comment: Im trying to implement in pure js

Comment: @user3282116 In that case, I will remove the query tag for you.

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773938/add-a-list-item-through-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle form submit properly. Instead of button click event you would better listen `onsubmit` form event:

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="return addUser()">
```

And from the function you need to return false to prevent form submission:

```
function addUser(){
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(username + ' ' + email));
    list.appendChild(entry);

    return false;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8846u/

Also note that making a button type `button` tag would also work but the best practice is actually to have `type="submit"`. Benefits it provides is that you can submit a form with Enter key which is nice and consistent form behavior.

Comment: How to validate the email field using ajax?

Comment: I would recommend to ask it as a separate question, it's too broad to answer it in comments.

Comment: here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828368/validate-email-field-in-the-form-while-adding-to-the-list

Answer (score 1):

Try This

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
<h2>Add a User:</h2>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="name">
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
 <button onclick='return addUser();' type="submit">add user</button>
</form>


<h2>UsersList:</h2>
<ul id="users"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
function addUser(){
    var list = document.getElementById('users');
var username =document.getElementById('username').value;
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var entry = document.createElement('li');
entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(username + ' ' + email));
list.appendChild(entry);
    return false;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RQt5R/1/)

Answer (score 0):

That button will submit the form, change the button type to `button` will fix it :

```
<button onclick='addUser()' type="button">add user</button>
```