# Pushing numbers being generated by a javascript "for" loop into an array and later print out each number out to HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```js
        var firstNum = 1;
        var secondNum = 2;
        var fibonacciNum;
        var myArray = [];

        for (var k = 3; k <=15; k++) {

            fibonacciNum = firstNum + secondNum;
            firstNum = secondNum;
            secondNum = fibonacciNum;
            
            myArray.push(fibonacciNum);

        }
```

im trying to push the numbers from the loop into myArray and later putting each number as a list item in an unordered list

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `Array.push` ?

Comment: `myArray.push(fibonacciNum)`

Comment: there is a better algorithm to provide Fibonacci numbers (using matrix multiplication)

Comment: im still new to javascript, so i understnd it this way. but how then do i later put the array values into an unordered list

Comment: check this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp

Comment: write `<ul id="fin"></ul>` in your html page, then in JS find this element using document.getElementById("fin") and apply the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773938/add-a-list-item-through-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
//fibonacciNum.push(myArray.length);
```

with

```
myArray.push(fibonacciNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming you want to add a new Unordered list to the DOM:
(this will work for any array...)

```
function addUl(arr) {
    //A <ul> is created and appended to the DOM
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.setAttribute("id", "list");
    document.body.appendChild(ul);

    var li;
    var element;
    //A <li> is created and filled with an element each time
    //the element will change to the next array element every lap (a)
    arr.forEach(function (a) {
        li = document.createElement("li");
        element = document.createTextNode(a);
        li.appendChild(element);
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    });
}
```

here you can se how it works:
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/xhhLhqvk/)

By the way, if you use jQuery your life will be easier...