# Make a list from Firebase data

Tags: javascript, firebase, dom

I´m trying to structure my Firebasedata using this example from Stackoverflow:
[Add a list item through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773938/add-a-list-item-through-javascript)

HTML:

```
 First name:
    <input type="text" id="firstname">
    <br>
    <p>Your first name is: <b id='boldStuff2'></b> 
    </p>
    <p>Other people's names:</p>
    <ol id="demo"></ol>
    <input type='button' onclick='changeText2();' value='Submit' />
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gmyag/)

When I try to copy the code straight into my project for testing, I´m getting the error:
 Uncaught ReferenceError: changeText2 is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick"

Also, when I try to copy the code to a new Fiddle, it doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Where are you declaring your `changeText2` function in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Did you define the `changeText2()` function? It seems like you are not declaring this function in your code.

Try to add the code below and check if this solves your error.

```
function changeText2(){
    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = firstname;
    x.push(firstname);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it working, just a stupid typo I missed in the js file... Sorry about that.