# Is there any way to add new list item using innerHTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to use innerHTML to add an `li` item according to user input (in a textbox). Is there any way to create new list item other than using `createElement` or `appendChild`?

```js
const user = document.getElementById('btn');
const inputEle = document.getElementById("submit");
const userList = document.getElementById('itemList');

user.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  userList.innerHTML += `<li>${inputEle.value}</li>`;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="submit">

<button type="button" id="btn">Add</button>

<ul id="itemList"></ul>
```

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773938/add-a-list-item-through-javascript

Comment: is there a reason for not creating an element or appending a child?

Comment: What is wrong with your proposed solution? I have created a snippet for you and it works fine.

Comment: My solution doesn't add multiple li items to my ul , it just adds 1  li item .

Comment: I don't understand. It works for me, I can add as many li as I want with your snippet

Comment: @AnotherOne Edit the Stack Snippet within your question so that it behaves in the way that you describe.

Comment: Your snippet is working really perfect :D

Comment: Thank you i found out that i have inserted button and input inside ul that is why it just works 1 time thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the problem is in html file,  where i put my button and input inside ul

```
<ul>
<input type="text"  id="submit" >
<button type="button" id="btn">Add</button>
</ul>
```